# delete or rollback an insert if a trigger on insert fails

Tags: sql-server, trigger, transaction

is it possible to delete or roll back insert statement if a trigger on that insert statement fails due to some reason.
for eg i have a trigger on `insert into employe(id,name) values(1,'ali')`
trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Customer_INSERT]
       ON [dbo].[employe]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
       DECLARE @id INT
 
       SELECT @id = INSERTED.id       
       FROM INSERTED
 
       INSERT INTO CustomerLogs
       VALUES(@id, 'Inserted')
END
```

now is there any way i can wrap all this up in one transaction so in case my trigger fails then the first inserted row is also removed?i know i can use try catch and delete in catch block
but i want to get it done with transaction is it possible?

Comment: Triggers execute in the same transaction context as the statement that fired the trigger. If the trigger errors, the trigger work and insert will be rolled back.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for the input
will it work if i am executing insert statement from entity framework orm and that insert statement is wrapped in (using) transaction?
if a trigger fails will the transaction.commit() rollback?as trigger is in db

Comment: Triggers execute with `SET XACT_ABORT ON` by default, which will rollback the transaction after an error. So if you attempt a `transaction.Commit()` after the error, that will fail because no transaction is active. Typically, one would commit at the end of the happy path, not after an error.

Comment: **[Brent Ozar says: The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/), your trigger does not take into account multi-row or zero-row inserts** Unclear why it is not just a straight `insert...select ... from inserted`

Comment: @Charlieface actually i just wrote a sample code to show what i want to achieve that isn't what i am using in reality
thanks and yes i am aware of this silent bug which fails for multi row insert

Comment: As @DanGuzman has told you, a trigger executes within the transaction, so any error automatically rolls back. Don't write your own error-handling in the trigger code, it's not necessary and can cause further problems